# The format change button when clicked is showing both 24 hours and 12 hours format at duration of 1 second why?

Tags: javascript, time

The format change button when clicked gives both 24hrs and 12hrs format at a duration of 1 second. This may be due to something logical error in my code which i cannot figure out.

```
const clock = document.querySelector('.time');
const date_data = document.querySelector('.date');
const day_display = document.querySelector('.day');
const format = document.querySelector('.format');

const tick_24 = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    const h = now.getHours();
    const m = now.getMinutes();
    const s = now.getSeconds();

    const html = `
    <span>${h}</span> :
    <span>${m}</span> :
    <span>${s}</span> 
    `;

    clock.innerHTML = html;
}
const tick_12 = () => {
    const now = new Date();
    const h = 30;
    const m = now.getMinutes();
    const s = now.getSeconds();
    let hour;
    if (h > 12) {
        hour = h - 12;
    } else {
        hour = h;
    }
    const html = `
    <span>${hour}</span> :
    <span>${m}</span> :
    <span>${s}</span> 
    `;

    clock.innerHTML = html;
}


const day_disp = () => {
    const now2 = new Date();
    const day = now2.getDay();
    let real_day = "";
    if (day === 0) {
        real_day = "Sun";
    } else if (day === 1) {
        real_day = "Mon";
    } else if (day === 2) {
        real_day = "Tue";
    } else if (day === 3) {
        real_day = "Wed";
    } else if (day === 4) {
        real_day = "Thu";
    } else if (day === 5) {
        real_day = "Fri";
    } else {
        real_day = "Sat";
    }
    const html = `${real_day}`;
    day_display.innerHTML = html;
}

const date_dis = () => {
    const now1 = new Date();
    const date_log = now1.getDate();
    const month = now1.getMonth();
    const year = now1.getFullYear();
    const html1 = `
    <span>${date_log}</span> : 
    <span>${month+1}</span> : 
    <span>${year}</span> 
    `;

    date_data.innerHTML = html1;
}
// const timer = () => setInterval(tick_12, 1000);
// timer();
let check = true;
const funct = () => {

    const timer1 = () => setInterval(tick_24, 1000);
    const timer2 = () => setInterval(tick_12, 1000);
    if (check === true) {
        timer1();
        clearInterval(timer2);
        check = false;
    } else {
        timer2();
        clearInterval(timer1);
        check = true;
    }
}

format.addEventListener('click',() => {
    funct();
})

const func = () => {
    date_dis();
    day_disp();
}
setInterval(func, 1000);
```

The expected results is that it must show 24hrs-format on one click and 12hrs-format on the other click and it must switch but it isn't working!

Comment: When you call setinterval, it spawns a new task, but it never cancels other running tasks

Comment: Clearinterval won't help here?